# AngularJS third party authorization in new browser window

Tags: angularjs, oauth, window, authorization

I am facing some difficulty with AngularJS and opening a new window(window.open('URL'))

Consider the scenario, I want clients on my web-app to authenticate via third-party services like Facebook, Stripe, etc.

I have my web-app built in AngularJS and bootstrap.
On click of 'Add Account' button, I would like to open a new window with the respective URL. Everything upto here works.

But when I try to access the window object from the parent web-app, it gives an error: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

I need to access the child window URL from the parent to detect URL change, and I also need to access the content of the child window.

So the whole workflow is

1. When I click on 'Add Account' from my web-app
2. A new window opens, which hits a URL on my Server
3. Which then calls the Stripe Authentication URL
4. The User signs-in with his Stripe credentials
5. After successful signing in, Stripe auth redirects the callback to my Server
6. Which then sends a ACK = Success
7. I then read the ACK from my web-app(parent)
8. After receiving the ACK, and checking it, close the new window which was opened

Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this,

You can have an intermediary page which opens the URL on your server. The server url returns with a hashtag #success or #error after the authentication with the third party page. The intermediary page loads again and looks for the hashtag and calls opener window.